# How to generate flutter code before every build

Tags: flutter

I'd like to have the output of some `git describe` call available inside my flutter app. It's important that this is run automatically before builds triggered by i.e. `flutter run` or `flutter build apk`. If I have to remember running a command manually before rebuilding the app in my IDE I won't get an accurate version number in the app.

I looked at https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner but that seems to require to always invoke it manually.

I also looked at [--dart-define](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2641) but through this I can just pass values into dart code but I also need a way to automatically update that value.

I *did* get this to work through gradle... but that is only invoked for android builds. Adding it additionally to the cmake layer would work... that still leaves web and iOS builds without a solution.

Anyone got an idea what I might be missing?

(flutter can already generate code for translations dynamically via the `generate: true` flag but this doesn't seem to be exposed through any way to add custom generation commands there?)